# Keeping symbology style in a polygon shapefile when converting to KML

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, shapefile, symbology, google-earth

I have a polygon shape with 23 classes and have created patterned symbology styles which I will like to have retained when I open in Google earth pro. Is there any how I can achieve this in either ArcMap or QGIS. My programming skills are very poor.

Comment: Not that I know of. Polygon/polyline symbology in Google Earth is pretty limited, I don't believe it can do things like hatching, dotted lines, etc. in its symbols. For point symbols, the Xtools Pro extension will export custom symbology as PNG files, but that only works with point layers.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't, try Arc's Layer to KML conversion.  I know it retains some symbology, but don't if it'll do the patterns. Worth a try, though.

Comment: Yes to me it works perfectly for retaining symbology...

Comment: Thanks, I have now realised Google earth doesn't keep lots of symbology so am making do with what is available.